# Reindexing and filling in missing dates

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that is in this format.

```
       country_txt  multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property      dates  \
1970Q1       Italy         0        1    0.0     0.0         0 1970-01-01   
1970Q1       Italy         0        0    0.0     0.0         1 1970-01-01   
1970Q4       Italy         0        0    0.0     0.0         1 1970-04-01   
1971Q1       Italy         0        1    0.0     0.0         1 1971-01-01   
1971Q3       Italy         0        1    0.0     0.0         1 1971-03-01
```

The index of this DataFrame is the year followed by the quarter which I created by using `PeriodIndex`. The `dates` column symbolizes the year and the quarter as well, the day of the month is irrelevant. I want to sum up all the other columns for each quarter. Normally thats not a problem since I can just do `italy.groupby('dates').sum()`. However, the output I get is this

```
            multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property  
dates                                                             
1970-01-01         0        1    0.0     0.0         1           
1970-04-01         0        0    0.0     0.0         1           
1971-01-01         0        1    0.0     0.0         1
```

The problem is now I want to fill in missing values for each quarter that does not appear so the output would look something like this instead,

```
                multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property  
dates                                                             
1970-01-01         0        1    0.0     0.0         1 
1970-02-01         0        0    0.0     0.0         0
1970-03-01         0        0    0.0     0.0         0
1970-04-01         0        0    0.0     0.0         1           
1971-01-01         0        1    0.0     0.0         1
```

I have looked up previous questions and found that people recommend I do this `df.reindex(pd.date_range("1970-01-01", "2015-12-31"), fill_value = 0)`. The problem is this, this will give my data lots of extra rows since I would have data on a daily basis, which would then mean I have to find a way to sum the data by quarter all over again. So how would I achieve this goal without creating all these daily 0's and finding a way to sum everything up again by quarter?

For reference, the `dates` column was created by first changing the original months column into a value from 1-4 (to signify quarter) and then converted to timedelta format by doing this

```
df['dates'] = df.iyear.astype(str).str.cat(df.imonth.astype(str))
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format = '%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** parsing real dates from the string index. It should work for older Pandas versions as well:

```
In [212]: df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index)).resample('QS').sum().fillna(0)
Out[212]:
            multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property
idx
1970-01-01       0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1970-04-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-07-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-10-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1971-01-01       0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1971-04-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1971-07-01       0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
```

**OLD answer**: (assuming the `dates` column contains real dates). It uses new Pandas 0.19.0 feature: `.resample(..., on='column_name')`:

try this:

```
In [205]: df.resample('QS', on='dates').sum().fillna(0)
Out[205]:
            multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property
dates
1970-01-01       0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1970-04-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1970-07-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-10-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1971-01-01       0.0      2.0    0.0     0.0       2.0
```

or resampled "monthly":

```
In [207]: df.resample('QS', on='dates').sum().resample('MS').sum().fillna(0)
Out[207]:
            multiple  success  nkill  nwound  property
dates
1970-01-01       0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1970-02-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-03-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-04-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       1.0
1970-05-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-06-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-07-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-08-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-09-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-10-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-11-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1970-12-01       0.0      0.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
1971-01-01       0.0      2.0    0.0     0.0       2.0
```

Comment: I am receiving this error `TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'`. And just to be clear, I am performing this command on the DataFrame that I have already used the `groupby` function on, is that correct?

Comment: I'm using new version of Pandas: 0.19.0. `resample(on='col_name')` - is a new feature of Pandas 0.19.0

Comment: New features +1.. well +1 for good answer and yay! new features.

Comment: I was able to use your solution by changing `on` to `axis = 0`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe due to compatibility issues of another library that I'm using which is in the development stage my version of Pandas has to remain at the older one for stability issues.